# doesn't send email with gmail smtp through fsockopen()

Tags: php, email

When I try send email with PHPMailer_v5.1, it works. But when I try make it self, I know that the result is possible to error or email not sent. My problem is the email not sent.
this my code:

```
<?php
$fp = fsockopen("ssl://smtp.gmail.com", 465, $errNo, $errStr, 15);
if(!$fp){
    echo "not connected";
}else{
    fputs($fp, "EHLO"."\r\n");
    fputs($fp, "AUTH LOGIN"."\r\n");
    fputs($fp, base64_encode("author@gmail.com")."\r\n");
    fputs($fp, base64_encode("password")."\r\n");
    fputs($fp, "MAIL FROM:<author@gmail.com>"."\r\n");
    fputs($fp, "RCPT TO:<target@gmail.com>"."\r\n");
    fputs($fp, "DATA"."\r\n");
    fputs($fp, "Subject: This is subject"."\r\n");
    fputs($fp, "This is body message"."\r\n");
    fputs($fp, "."."\r\n");
    fputs($fp, "QUIT"."\r\n");
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

sorry, my english is bad.

Comment: You're not using SSL. You might think you are, but you're not, and GMail will not accept mail submission without it.

Comment: I've read some reference in php.net, and it said just enable `extension=php_openssl.dll` in php.ini to using SSL. or it needs something to enable the SSL ?

Comment: Just read the docs, and you're right. I didn't think `fsockopen()` had stream wrapper support. Let me get some code together and I'll post an answer that should help.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is that you're treating SMTP as a one-way street and simply blasting out commands without ever checking the responses.

The first thing you should be doing after connection is reading the server banner, and then after every command you should be reading the server's response. Waiting on the server banner is important because with a busy MTA you might have to wait up to a minute to actually have the transaction start. Here is the annotated version of my EHLO function of the mailer I wrote for funsies:

```
private function do_ehlo() {
    // most MTAs expect a domain/host name, and the picky ones want the hostname specified here
    // to match the reverse lookup of the IP address.
    $ehlo = sprintf("EHLO %s\r\n", $this->connection_info['domain']);
    $this->log($ehlo, 'out');
    fwrite($this->sock, $ehlo, strlen($ehlo));

    // SMTP responses can span multiple lines, they will look like
    // ###-First line
    // ###-Second line
    // ### Last line
    //
    // Where ### is the 3-digit status code, and every line but the last has a dash between the
    // code and the text.
    while( $get = fgets($this->sock, 1024) ) {
        $this->log($get, 'in');
        if( ! preg_match('/^([0-9]{3})([ -])(.*)$/', $get, $matches) || $matches[1] != '250' ) {
            Throw new Exception('Abnormal EHLO repsonse received: ' . $get);
        }
        // The advertised capabilities of the server in the EHLO response will include the types
        // of AUTH mechanisms that are supported, which is important, because LOGIN is just
        // gussied-up plaintext, and plaintext is bad.
        $this->capabilities[] = trim($matches[3]);
        // stop trying to read from the socket if a space is detected, indicating either a 
        // single-line response, or the last line of a multi-line response.
        if( $matches[2] == ' ' ) { break; }
    }
}
```

IIRC GMail is particularly picky about adherence to the rules, and they might be kicking you to the curb right off the bat for not specifying a proper name in the `EHLO`, or even just for missing the space after the colons in your `MAIL FROM` and `RCPT TO` commands. If you want to get real picky, you're also not setting a `Date` header in the message data, which I believe is also a big nono for strict servers, use: `sprintf('Date: %s', date(DATE_RFC2822));`

Lastly, if you want to write your own mailer you should start by reading [RF2822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt), [RFC821](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc821.txt), and [RFC2821](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt). Just make sure you have some strong coffee on hand, otherwise you'll be asleep in no time.

**TL;DR:** PHPmailer is way easier.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I try to add delay after fputs() execution. And, it works. `fputs($fp, "EHLO"."\r\n");Sleep(5);fputs($fp, "AUTH LOGIN"."\r\n");Sleep(5)...etc`